# Error starting application using ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I started studying the ZendFramework. Configured as recommended. When calling the project created with the default code, it works perfectly. When I comment all index.php and add the code:

index.php

```
<?php

include 'Zend.php';

Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Controller_Front');

Zend_Controller_Front::run('controllers');

?>

<html>
<head>
   <title>Chomp! The online feedreader</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr><td colspan="2">
   <h1>CHOMP!</h1>
   <h3>the only feedreader you'll ever need</h3>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="width: 200px;">Login info here</td><td>Content here</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

indexController.php

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
    }

    //Add por Debora
    public function loginAction()
    {
        echo "This is the loginAction().";
    }

    public function registerAction()
    {
        echo "This is the registerAction().";
    }


}
```

Shows the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Loader' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\ProjetoZend\public\index.php on line 5

Could anyone help me?

Thank You!

Comment: Did you comment out any other includes?

Comment: There is no other include, in the example I'm using. I will edit all the file.

Comment: What is the Zend.php file? There is no such file in ZF1 Project...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include the actual loader file and not some file that probably doesn't even exist.

```
// this will not help you access your Zend_Loader class
include 'Zend.php';

// something like this
include '/path/to/library/Zend/Loader.php'
```

**Additional Note:** Your setup may not work until you include the path to the Zend library in your path with `set_include_path()`